# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. in session.run

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a model using the word Embedding vector. When I load the data of the vector it gets an error when it comes to running the session.

I saw many posts for the same error but none of them really helped me. 
My code is the following:

```
# Build vocabulary
max_document_length = max([len(x.split(" ")) for x in x_text])
if (not use_glove):
    print ("Not using GloVe")
    vocab_processor = learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(max_document_length)
    x = np.array(list(vocab_processor.fit_transform(x_text)))
else:
    print ("Using GloVe")
    embedding_dim = 50
    filename = 'glove.twitter.27B.50d.txt'
    def loadGloVe(filename):
        vocab = []
        embd = []
        file = open(filename,'r')
        for line in file.readlines():
            row = line.strip().split(' ')
            vocab.append(row[0])
            embd.append(row[1:])
        print('Loaded GloVe!')
        file.close()
        return vocab,embd
    vocab,embd = loadGloVe(filename)
    vocab_size = len(vocab)
    embedding_dim = len(embd[0])
    embedding = np.asarray(embd)

    W = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[vocab_size, embedding_dim]),
                    trainable=False, name="W")
    embedding_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [vocab_size, embedding_dim])
    embedding_init = W.assign(embedding_placeholder)
    # embedding_init = np.vstack([np.expand_dims(x, 0) for x in embedding_init])

    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=False)
    sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
    sess.run(embedding_init, feed_dict={embedding_placeholder: embedding})
```

The error I get is the following:

```
>> python train.py
Loading data...
Using GloVe
Loaded GloVe!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 88, in <module>
    embedding = np.asarray(embd, dtype=float)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
rudaina:CS291K-master rudaina$ python train.py
Loading data...
Using GloVe
Loaded GloVe!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 88, in <module>
    embedding = np.asarray(embd, dtype=float)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

When I print embedding I get the following:

> [list(['0.78704', '0.72151', '0.29148', '-0.056527', '0.31683',
>   '0.47172', '0.023461', '0.69568', '0.20782', '0.60985', '-0.22386',
>   '0.7481', '-2.6208', '0.20117', '-0.48104', '0.12897', '0.035239',
>   '-0.24486', '-0.36088', '0.026686', '0.28978', '-0.10698', '-0.34621',
>   '0.021053', '0.54514', '-1.0958', '-0.274', '0.2233', '1.0827',
>   '-0.029018', '-0.84029', '0.58619', '-0.36511', '0.34016', '0.89615',
>   '0.32757', '0.24267', '0.68404', '-0.34374', '0.13583', '-2.2162',
>   '-0.42537', '0.46157', '0.88626', '-0.22014', '0.025599', '-0.38615',
>   '0.080107', '-0.075323', '-0.61461'])  list(['0.68661', '-1.0772',
>   '0.011114', '-0.24075', '-0.3422', '0.64456', '0.54957', '0.30411',
>   '-0.54682', '1.4695', '0.43648', '-0.34223', '-2.7189', '0.46021',
>   '0.016881', '0.13953', '0.020913', '0.050963', '-0.48108', '-1.0764',
>   '-0.16807', '-0.014315', '-0.55055', '0.67823', '0.24359', '-1.3179',
>   '-0.036348', '-0.228', '1.0337', '-0.53221', '-0.52934', '0.35537',
>   '-0.44911', '0.79506', '0.56947', '0.071642', '-0.27455', '-0.056911',
>   '-0.42961', '-0.64412', '-1.3495', '0.23258', '0.25383', '-0.10226',
>   '0.65824', '0.16015', '0.20959', '-0.067516', '-0.51952', '-0.34922'])
>   list(['0.98483', '0.19784', '0.28403', '0.35406', '0.2438', '0.42519',
>   '-0.050784', '0.48965', '0.18231', '0.45225', '0.60871', '0.1023',
>   '-2.246', '0.47362', '-0.20073', '-0.21838', '-0.58847', '0.23933',
>   '0.47089', '-0.96444', '-0.06588', '-0.26914', '-0.58221', '-0.26283',
>   '0.67984', '-0.87678', '-0.091667', '0.18128', '1.0218', '0.23728',
>   '-1.0547', '0.19766', '-0.86072', '0.6021', '0.69374', '0.32242',
>   '-0.074545', '0.38367', '0.28661', '-0.41465', '-2.882', '-0.30393',
>   '0.047981', '1.0937', '0.4184', '-0.68958', '-0.45923', '0.23368',
>   '-0.30628', '-0.093607'])  ...  list(['0.84287', '0.36278', '-1.7695',
>   '1.0011', '-0.035064', '0.51417', '-1.5918', '0.85464', '1.0441',
>   '-0.19218', '0.91523', '1.2206', '0.6551', '-0.48092', '0.89536',
>   '-0.51738', '-0.113', '-0.14132', '0.69741', '-0.094937', '-0.046912',
>   '-0.2098', '-0.029853', '0.49541', '0.66782', '0.23435', '1.6776',
>   '0.13993', '1.2205', '0.11827', '0.4398', '-0.37945', '0.26414',
>   '0.63263', '-0.48117', '-0.95508', '-0.39435', '-2.8466', '-0.64169',
>   '0.61715', '3.0288', '1.2714', '-2.1379', '-0.11995', '-1.5553',
>   '-0.17096', '-0.30855', '-0.24573', '0.63324', '-0.80304']) 
>   list(['0.82853', '-1.4966', '-0.33163', '-1.7248', '0.75364',
>   '-0.66916', '0.21631', '0.54184', '-0.18342', '0.4248', '0.21309',
>   '0.21076', '0.60751', '-0.31577', '0.5663', '0.10905', '0.12388',
>   '-1.0154', '0.32227', '-0.92746', '-0.59573', '-0.8008', '1.146',
>   '1.1625', '0.32181', '0.30272', '0.99954', '-1.4012', '0.076173',
>   '-0.081811', '1.7618', '1.0314', '1.2658', '1.3319', '0.52592',
>   '-0.30999', '-1.4563', '-1.4165', '0.21875', '0.36172', '2.7735',
>   '0.20257', '0.074379', '-0.020002', '-1.0133', '0.56882', '-0.17648',
>   '0.3729', '0.76953', '1.4394'])  list(['-2.3613', '-0.94632',
>   '-1.8524', '1.545', '0.29188', '0.21677', '0.090334', '-1.4557',
>   '0.80716', '-0.88994', '-1.1031', '0.002139', '1.211', '-0.069074',
>   '1.1984', '0.93501', '1.0359', '-0.17041', '0.44013', '-1.7879',
>   '0.61577', '0.52878', '0.32978', '-0.82872', '0.48385', '0.76497',
>   '-0.64303', '0.18897', '0.3698', '0.62647', '1.7118', '-0.2942',
>   '-0.26316', '-0.35169', '-0.72771', '-0.71678', '0.91815', '-0.56122',
>   '0.51562', '-0.030861', '-0.017585', '-0.58224', '-0.98393',
>   '0.85906', '-0.67031', '0.34382', '-0.41876', '-0.40575', '-0.53006',
>   '-0.20514'])]

How can I fix this?  spent so much time trying to fix it while it seems a simple way but I did not know it.

Comment: This error happens when you try to make a numpy array out of a list of individual arrays that do not have the same sizes, and since you are forcing the dtype to float, then it cannot make a numpy array. Please check that all list elements have the same number of elements.

Comment: I tried without forcing the type but I get the same error.  I edited the post with a sample output of the array lists.

Comment: You should convert all those strings into actual floats, but the output does not tell much, please check that all list elements have the same number of elements.

Comment: Just as an example, this code produces the same error: np.asarray([[1,2],[1]], dtype=float)

Answer (score 0):

This will happens when you try to create a NumPy array from a list of individual arrays that do not have the same size. I encountered this problem when reading GloVe file by manually splitting every row by space character, like you do.

If our glove.twitter.27B.50d.txt is the same file, line number 38523 contains

```
0.065581 0.39605 -0.96669 0.23706 -0.41379 -0.97006 0.16601 -1.292 -0.58989 0.11632 -1.365 -0.27939 -0.57222 -0.97108 -0.56319 -0.015263 -0.70465 -0.13867 1.0702 -0.25557 0.25122 -0.87755 0.70999 0.9118 -0.30077
```

The vocab seems like a non-printable character to me. It will cause the code to read the first Embedding vector as vocab, and you get less number of Embedding vector (as in your case 49 dimensions) at that specific line.

The exact same line can also be found in glove.twitter.27B.25d.txt, glove.twitter.27B.100d.txt, and glove.twitter.27B.200d.txt

The quick and dirty solution that works are:

```
for line in file.readlines():
    row = line.strip().split(' ')
    if len(row)-1 < embedding_dim:
        row.insert(0, '')
    vocab.append(row[0])
    embd.append(row[1:])
```